# Image not found error while trying to import gdal in python

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, gdal

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/rit/anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I am getting the error above when I try to `import gdal`. How can I fix it? I reinstalled gdal using `conda uninstall gdal` and the `conda install gdal`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `jpeg` package wasn't installed for some reason. Can you try doing `conda install jpeg`? What does `conda info jpeg` report?

Perhaps try doing this in a fresh environment. Something like

```
conda create -n gdal-test python=2.7 gdal
source activate gdal-test
```

And then `import gdal`.